# awk append in CSV file

Tags: bash, awk

How to use `awk` command, as I need to add or append a `000` to my below timestamp column. I try to use the below command,

```
head -n 10000001 ratings.csv | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1 "000"}' >> ratings_1.csv
```

but data is not as expected.

```
$ cat ratings.csv |wc -l
20000264
$ head ratings.csv
userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
1,2,3.5,1112486027
1,29,3.5,1112484676
1,32,3.5,1112484819
1,47,3.5,1112484727
1,50,3.5,1112484580
1,112,3.5,1094785740
1,151,4.0,1094785734
1,223,4.0,1112485573
1,253,4.0,1112484940
```

My expected output should look like

```
1,2,3.5,1112486027000
```

Comment: You want to add it for all the lines? or only for the 1st line after header?

Comment: Make sure your expected output is EXACTLY the expected output for the input you posted. That means, for example, if you have 10 lines of input and want 10 lines of output then show those 10 lines of output.

Comment: In what way is the data "not as expected"? If I isolate your awk command, as in `echo '1,2,3.5,1112486027' | awk '{print $1 "000"}'` it works fine. There's something  else we need to get to the bottom of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ if (NR > 1) { $1 = $1 "000" } print }'
```

Maybe a faster version that wouldn't run the `if` on every line would be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { getline; print } { print $0 "000" }'
```